# Is there a standard command-line tool to do a hostname lookup?

Tags: linux, shell

I am in the shell and I want to know the corresponding IP address(es) for a hostname.

I know I could get it through Perl, PHP, Python or a number of other scripting languages (probably even awk!), and this will be my workaround, but I am surprised that there seems to be no command-line tool to do this, no simple wrapper around `getaddrinfo()`.

Am I wrong? Is there one? `host` and `getent` do not count, I want something that uses the libc and acts according to `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and something that is probably installed on any (linux) system by default.

Answer from https://superuser.com/questions/681612/is-there-a-standard-command-line-tool-to-do-a-hostname-lookup : `getent hosts` does actually do exactly what I want, not just an `/etc/hosts` lookup.

Comment: On second thought, this should have been asked on superuser or serverfault instead.

Comment: Moved to http://superuser.com/questions/681612/is-there-a-standard-command-line-tool-to-do-a-hostname-lookup

Comment: Reposting the very same question to another site is not how moving questions works: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/moving-my-own-question-to-another-stackexchange-site

Comment: Thank you. I will do this next time.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to leverage `arp` which follows `nsswitch.conf` settings, only uses `libc` and is available on any Linux/Unix system, eg:

```
$ arp stackoverflow.com | sed -e 's/.*(//' -e 's/).*$//'
198.252.206.16
```

Here is a shell function using this method that also workaround the issue reported by clacke:

```
resolve()
{
  : ${1:?Usage: resolve name}
  (
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
    ao=$(arp $1)
    [ "$(echo "$ao"|grep HWaddress)" ] && ao=$(arp -a $1)
    echo "$ao" | sed -e 's/.*(//' -e 's/).*$//'
  )
}
```

Comment: On RHEL 6, if the host actually has a MAC available in the arp table, `arp` shows a table with MAC address and other things, but not the IP number. Your examples are unlucky enough to not be local physical net addresses, so they are missing this case.

Comment: @clacke I was unlucky enough indeed ! Answer updated.

Comment: Not work with IPv6 only domain

Comment: Good, but the sed part doesn't always work.

Comment: @RonJohn What returns `arp stackoverflow.com` in such case?

Comment: the sed command works perfectly with `stackoverflow.com`, which that server has never used except with arp: specifically "stackexchange.com (151.101.65.69) -- no entry".  However, `arp` on a server which is already in the cache returns something completely different.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use resolveip command

```
#resolveip -s hostname
```

or use the most common command : ping

```
#ping -c 1 hostname | cut -d " " -f 3 | egrep 1
```

Comment: `yum provides *bin/resolveip`
`mysql-server-5.1.66-2.el6_3.x86_64 : The MySQL server and related files` MySQL is not installed on all linux systems by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dig` command:

```
$ dig stackoverflow.com
; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> stackoverflow.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45432
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;stackoverflow.com.             IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
stackoverflow.com.      197     IN      A       198.252.206.16

;; Query time: 26 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 26 09:28:10 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 51
```

As you can see there is only one line without `;` at the beginning so it would be possible to `grep` it and get the IP address by constructing a pipe:

```
$ dig stackoverflow.com | grep -e "^[^;]" | tr -s " \t" " " | cut -d" " -f5
198.252.206.16
```

Comment: It won't resolve entries defined in /etc/hosts, ldap, nis and whatever other hosts backend service defined in /etc/nsswitch.conf

Answer (score 0):

What about nslookup?

```
$ nslookup stackoverflow.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 198.252.206.16
```

Comment: It won't resolve entries defined in `/etc/hosts`, `ldap`, `nis` and whatever other hosts backend service defined in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Debian-based distro:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libsocket-getaddrinfo-perl
socket_getaddrinfo one.one.one.one

# Resolved host 'one.one.one.one', service '0'
# 
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) + '1.1.1.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP) + '1.1.1.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW   , IPPROTO_IP ) + '1.1.1.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) + '1.0.0.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP) + '1.0.0.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW   , IPPROTO_IP ) + '1.0.0.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) + '[2606:4700:4700::1111]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP) + '[2606:4700:4700::1111]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW   , IPPROTO_IP ) + '[2606:4700:4700::1111]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) + '[2606:4700:4700::1001]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP) + '[2606:4700:4700::1001]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW   , IPPROTO_IP ) + '[2606:4700:4700::1001]:0'

socket_getaddrinfo localhost

# Resolved host 'localhost', service '0'
# 
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) + '[::1]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP) + '[::1]:0'
# socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW   , IPPROTO_IP ) + '[::1]:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) + '127.0.0.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_DGRAM , IPPROTO_UDP) + '127.0.0.1:0'
# socket(AF_INET , SOCK_RAW   , IPPROTO_IP ) + '127.0.0.1:0'
```